# Scripture showing ways to summon Gandharva, Yaksha and Kinnar

Tags: demi-god, gandharva, yakshas

Is there any Scripture which provides complete information on how to summon Gandharva, Yaksha and Kinnar?

Comment: Some Yaksha Sadhanas are given in Damara Tantras.

Comment: @Rickross Thanks what about Gandharva and Kinnars. Also note that it should be summoning ritual not any normal Mantra.

Comment: Well there are certain Sadhanas like that which are done to make Vetals, Apasras and such celestial beings to work for helping us in many ways. Such forms of Sadhanas all come from the Damaras. There's nothing called summoning ritual in Hinduism. It's called invocation of the deity and which is done with the use of Mantras/Slokas only.

Comment: You might be knowing about the story of Vikram-Vetala. Then that King Vikramaditya did one such Vetala Sadhana and obtained mastery in it. Similar kinds of Sadhanas are there that involve Yakshas, Apasras etc. Might be there for Gandharvas too.

Comment: @Rickross ok so Damara Tantra contains sadhanas for every celestial being?

Comment: There are many Damara Tantras. I have not read all of them. But the kind of Sadhanas you are looking for are only found in the Damaras AFAIK. No other scriptures or Tantras have anything relevant in them.

Comment: @Rickross ok, so if you could answer my question with full name of that Tantra or book...it will be great

Comment: Bro I know the scripture name. Apart from that I don't have anything else to cite in the answer. BTW, how's ur health doing now? I guess u used to be "salvation" previously? :D

Comment: @Rickross Ok. So just name the scripture in the answer. I am fine now :) Yes..how u know?

Comment: Well I saw u deleted some chatroom or removed ur previous id from being the owner of that chatroom.. that's how .

Comment: @Rickross yes, I was trying to become the owner of that chatroom. So I deleted my other id...

Comment: @Rickross are you able to answer this question?

Comment: Ok let me see. Give me some time. @Ram

Comment: Anyone who wants this information, should probably not have access to it

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī not understood, what you mean?

Comment: @Ram did you figure it out the word

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have recently bought the KAmAkhyA Tantram. The 5th chapter of this text is called "Mohini VidyA". In that chapter Lord Shiva tells Goddess PArvati different Mantras and methods of  "Mohana KAryas" or methods of attracting beings.

There a Mantra is given that will attract every beings when mastered. It is capable of attracting (or summoning like you have said) Yakshas, deities, evil beings, human beings and everyone and even everything.

The Mantra is given in a code (as is quite usual in the Tantras):

> ChaturthavarnamAkrishya dvitiya varga samsthitam |
>  KritvA trividha
>   hAhAntam tadante he dvitiyakam ||
>  AmkAram shirasam kritva
>   pratykshara prajApanam |
>  **SahsrArdhasya japena phalam bhavati
>   shAshvatam ||**

In the  above quote the first 3 lines are containing the Mantra in a hidden code which when decoded gives us a 8-lettered Mantra (which is not safe to give here).

The line which is highlighted says that **"Siddhi of the Mantra will be attained by 500 chants only."**

The utility or the power of the Mantra is given by Lord Shiva in the next verse:

> MAnushyAsuradevAshcha yakshoragarAkshasAh |
>  SthAvarA
>   jangamAishchava AkrishtA ste varAngane ||
>
> This attracting Mantra (Mohini VidyA) can attract human beings,
>   demons, gods, Yakshas, NAgas, RAkshAs and everything movable and
>   immovable.

So, KAmAkhyA Tantram is one such text you are looking for.

In the last chapter of [the Brihat TantrasAra](http://www.shivashakti.com/tantrasara.htm), the author says that "I have covered hundreds of Tantras in this book but with the exception of the following scriptures and texts ---- **BhutadAmara, JyAnasamkalini Tantram, IndrajAlam, Uddisha Tantram, ShAvara Tantram, Pavanavijayaswarodaya, KAmaratna Tantram, Kriyoddisha Tantra, Yaksha DAmara Tantram, RasAyana Tantram, Brihat Bhuta DAmara, SiddhanAgarjuna Kakshaputa, Krikalasha DipikA** etc."

The reason why these Tantras are not included in TantrasAra is that they contain some Itara Yoni SAdhanas in them. Itara Yoni here means "non-divine Yonis" or demi-god Yonis. So, Yakshini, Gandharva, Apasara SAdhanas and many more are to be found in the above mentioned scriptures. So, they need to be dealt with separately and can not be included in the text that primarily focuses on deity worship or DevatA Pujan.

So, those (highlighted ones) are few more such scriptures where the things that you are looking for are found.

Comment: please let me know that 8 lettered Mantra in chat

Comment: @Ram Bro I'm very much reluctant to give this one. Because it is part of Vashikarana Sadhana and there are many rules to be followed. One who's practicing such Sadhanas must have the full knowledge of what he is doing. Anyways where is the chatroom? The room where we used to chat previously is now dead :D

Comment: My bad, as I tried to change the owner to me but I deleted it. can you create a chat room, I don't have  access to create chat rooms

Comment: @Ram I have created a room. Check for it among the chatrooms. Ping me there.

Comment: please correct the above answer as this mantra is not in fifth chapter of Kamakhya tantram

Comment: It is there in the book. The answer is of course correct. Chk my mail regarding this. @Ram

Comment: i have answered the mail. It is not 5th chapter. There is no fifth chapter called Mohini Vidya.

Comment: can you just click a photo and send it to me. I will accept the answer.

Comment: my intention was not to offend you. I just need a proof. You can mail me please. I hope you can understand my point of view. A complete chapter is missing. Thats the reason.

Comment: @Rickross can you suggest any book ti begin with into the word of attracting Devas & Siddhas, My only objective is to get brilliance and fame from demi gods.

Comment: I mostly read books related to Tantras in my own mother tongue (Bengali). You prefer which language? @STEEL

Comment: @Rickross I found there is something called Yakshini Sadhana wud like to know your views on this too. I prefer Hindi/English, even Sanskrit is fine as long as the book is not available in Hindi or Eng

Comment: Yes there are Yakshi sadhana, Apsara sadhana etc.. .. but I don't think it is recommended to do those on one's own just by seeing books. @STEEL

Comment: @STEEL see this (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32961/4732) ... Bhuta Damara Tantram is one such scripture where such sadhanas are mentioned. It can be easily found on net in English.

Comment: @Rickross thanks I'm at moment just trying to learn Meditation, I see on internet its not advised for newbie like me to start with Yakshini sadhana. if you also guide me on Meditation books that would be great, especially with any beej mantra. thanks

Comment: You can try to find videos on Youtube which deal with Chakra meditation .. there Beeja mantras are used and it's not that difficult. Sorry for replying late @STEEL