# Where can I find the sadhana for the Vidyadharas?

Tags: mantras, tantra, sadhana

Where can I find the mantras and sadhana for the Vidyadharas? I was able to find some information from a Buddhist source, but not from any Hindu one. Which Hindu scriptures would most likely mention any rituals relating to the Vidyadharas?

Comment: Related or a duplicate of [Scripture showing ways to summon Gandharva, Yaksha and Kinnar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28116/5212)

Comment: @Sarvabhouma Not a duplicate since it's not easy to find a sadhana for Vidyadharas, like for Gandharva, Yaksha and Kinnar

Comment: I said related. Who are the Vidhyadharas you are speaking of? Are they demigods? In Hinduism, vidhyadharas are celestial beings and I think their worship will same as Yaksha, Gandharava. You have to specify which ones are you speaking of as the terms from Buddhism and Hinduism have totally different meanings.