# How much Tapas should one do for Indra to send down an Apsara for him?

Tags: indra, apsaras

Indra frequently sends down Apsaras for men who try to do lots of Tapas to distract them.

Suppose one wants to intentionally get an Apsara. How much Tapas should one do for Indra to send down an Apsara for him?

Comment: I hv answered exactly abt that :D @Partha

Comment: There are no demi-gods in Hinduism @rickross.  Bu this is cool stuff - I thought only Muslims got 72 virgins - so we can get an Apsaras sent down to earth while we live?  This I gotta try :-)

Comment: To differentiate between the gods and the Apsaras, Gandharvas, Yakshas etc I used the word .. To use it for Vedic deities like Indra, Agni, Varuna is completely inappropriate @SK

Comment: Yes that is very the purpose of Apsara/Yaksini/Sundari etc Sadhanas It is not my recommendation though that u try it ..@SK

Comment: When Yagnas from Vedas are adviced to achieve material gain, why not this?

Comment: Why people chose words Demi God over Devas, caste over jati/Varna? Why create so much confusion?

Comment: @Lokesh Because people are speaking in English.

Comment: Don't get hyper over nothing .. to differentiate the gods (devatAs) from the Apasras, Gandharavas etc that word was used .. we can't say that the Apsaras are gods which they are clearly not .. also don't know whether u know or not I was the one who wrote an answer that there is nothing demi-god in Hinduism @Lokesh

Comment: Why can't you simply use the right words? Gods are not the same as devtas, nor is demons the same as daityas. Already enough distortion has been done.

Comment: And I'm not getting hyper over nothing. Today caste system is a result of mere ignorance. There's doesn't exist anything like pure birth, impure birth. Another example is use of words like Supreme God, Personality of Godhead.

Comment: I always use the right words where do u find me not doing the same? and this not about caste or anything ..@Lokesh

Comment: I meant to address @Ikshvaku.

Comment: Rickross, What is sundari sadhana that you mentioned? Could you please explain? Or someone tell me their names?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is something called *Apsara Sadhana* in Hinduism particularly in the DAmara Tantras. By which one can gain control over the Apsaras. Apsaras will come fulfill the aspirant's wishes and also stay with him as his wife (BhAryA).

Therefore, Indra's favor or intervention will not be needed.

One such Tantric scripture is the [Bhuta DAmara Tantram](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/bhuta-damara-tantra-authoritative-tantra-of-sri-krodha-bhairava-along-with-his-mantras-mandal-worship-rituals-and-accomplishment-rituals-of-bhutinis-yakshinis-snake-girls-etc-NAK836/).

The 10th Chapter of this text is dedicated completely to Apsara Sadhana.

The aspirant has to practice the Mantra of the desired Apsara and achieve Siddhi (mastery) in it. The Prayogas and details related to this practice are found in the same text.

The Chapter ends with the line:

> Iti Bhuta DAmare Apsarah SAdhanam NAma Dashamah Patalah |  Thus ends
>   the 10th Chapter named Apsarah Sadhana in the Bhuta DAmara Tantram

Mantras, Prayogas, MudrAs etc are given in this chapter for seven Apsaras including some well-known ones like Urvashi and RambhA.

> PrAleyam shri shashi devyA anAdi shri tilottamA |
>  SAnAdim shrim
>   manum smritya yuktam kAnchanmAlaya |
>  Visham shri varma
>   samyuktamAbhAshya kulahArini ||
>  TAram varna samAyuktAm ratnamAleti
>   panchami |
>  TAm sa iti rambhAkhyAm visham shrim urvashi parA | ....
>   (10.3)

The above verses are containing, in coded forms, the Mantras for the 7 Apasaras viz: Tilottama, KAnchanmAlA, KulahArini, RatnamAlA, RambhA, Urvashi and RamAbhushani.

> Atha vakshyeha apsaro vasyokArakam manumuttam |
>  Visham chaladvaram
>   proktvA amukim vashamAnaya |
>
> Now, the mantra for gaining control over the Apsaras are being spoken.
>   By chanting this mantra the Apsaras remain controlled (Vashibhuta).
>
> 10.13

If the aspirant is successful in the SAdhanA, then in the night time the Apsara comes to the aspirant's place and becomes his wife and presents him with gemstones, gold ornaments, heavenly food etc etc..

During the days, in which the aspirant is getting her favor, he should entirely forsake cohabiting with any other women. Otherwise, he has to face the wrath of the Apsara.

Comment: What rules are there to use?

Comment: What rules means? @Haridasa