# Can a sadhak who has completed Apsara sadhna take her as a lover and hence (possibly) have intercourse with the said Apsara?

Tags: apsaras

I heard this from a YouTube channel that makes videos on the ways to perform a Sadhna,along with some narrations of interaction between sadhaks and the invoked being.

https://youtu.be/ZeAN7Eb1aUk

From the 16th to 20th minute is where the point of my question comes,although the being invoked is “Maa Tara”.

I wanted to know if this is true for Apsaras as well,as I had also heard it so from another video of the same channel,if I am not wrong.

Comment: Scriptures contain all sorts of ideas and things for all kinds of audience. However, imo, it seems counter-intuitive to the concept of sādhanā, that a sādhak will carve for "intercourse".

Comment: I’m fairly new to this idea of Sadhna,in say a tantric sense.But since Apsaras are by nature sexually promiscuous,it does seem reasonable that the sadhak is to be either specifically prohibited,or permitted for carnal pleasure with the Apsara,I am just not sure.

Comment: You can see this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/32961/4732. It has some details you want. @Amethyst

Comment: @Rickross Man,I’ve seen your comments at a lot of questions,and I must say I’m impressed!.The YouTube source is congruent with the answer you gave,I’d like to add some more details.The video tells that the Apsara had given an option of being with the sadhak as his mother/lover.The sadhak says that as his mother,the Apsara cannot do anything for him,so he asks her to be his lover and give good fortune;but he strictly forbids lust/carnal pleasure.My question was whether lust/intercourse  with the Apsara is prohibited;your answers’ last parts indicates - it isn’t(apsara demands loyalty)

Comment: Yes the Sadhak will be given actually 3 options. Sadhak can accept the Apsara as his mother, sister or lover. Sexual intercourse is permitted only in the lover case and during that time the Sadahak can't cohabit with any other woman. In the other two cases, the Sadhak will be provided by the Apsara various pleasures of the heavens but sexual intercourse isn't permitted. @Amethyst

Comment: @Rickross Thanks a lot man,appreciate your answer!My doubts regarding this are gone.Also,I had posted some other questions,how long will it take for someone to answer those as well(as a proper answer,and not a comment)?

Comment: Not sure how long it will take. As soon as users knowing the answers see the question they are expected to answer .. @Amethyst