# How to increase aakarshan/mohini shakti?

Tags: mahabharata, mantras, tantra, ayurveda, yantra

I want to know how to increase aakarshan shakti, any kind of mantra or yantra which doesn't need initiation or any ayurvedic medicine

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There are some ayurvedic medicine which can increase your attraction power and some mantras I'm asking about them

Comment: Just do tratak regularly, no mantra recitation or initiation needed.

Answer (score 1):

छतुर्थवर्नमाक्रिश्य द्वितिय वर्ग सम्स्थितम् ।
ख़्रित्वा त्रिविध हाहान्तम् तदन्ते हे द्वितियकम् ॥
आम्कारम् शिरसम् क्रित्व प्रत्य्क्शर प्रजापनम् ।
षह्स्रार्धस्य जपेन फलम् भवति शाश्वतम् ॥
उपरोक्त उद्धरण में पहली 3 पंक्तियों में एक छिपे हुए कोड में मंत्र है, जो विभाजित होने पर हमें एक 8 अक्षरों वाला मंत्र देता है (जो यहां देना सुरक्षित नहीं है)
This is what I found here and it's exactly what I was looking for as well..
[Scripture showing ways to summon Gandharva, Yaksha and Kinnar](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/28116/scripture-showing-ways-to-summon-gandharva-yaksha-and-kinnar)
Please check this out you might find more

Comment: I've been trying for weeks trying to figure out the ""8 LETTERED MANTRA "" WHICH @Rickross mentioned in the link above

Comment: Can you atleast translate in hindi or can you pls share anything other than this